# Where can I set target step for failed purchase?

Tags: sylius

I am using custom checkout scenario which doesn't contain step "payment". However when purchase step fails, it tries to redirect to payment. Where can I change this behaviour?
Thanks.

**Updated:**

*ChceckoutProcessScenario.php*

```
class CheckoutProcessScenario implements ProcessScenarioInterface
{
  public function build(ProcessBuilderInterface $builder)
  {
    $cart = $this->getCurrentCart();

    $builder
        ->add('security', 'sylius_checkout_security')
        ->add('delivery', new Step\DeliveryStep())
        ->add('finalize', 'sylius_checkout_finalize')
        ->add('purchase', 'sylius_checkout_purchase')
    ;

    $builder
        ->setDisplayRoute('sylius_checkout_display')
        ->setForwardRoute('sylius_checkout_forward')
        ->setRedirect('sylius_homepage')
        ->validate(function () use ($cart) {
            return !$cart->isEmpty();
        })
    ;
  }
  ...
}
```

*app/config/config.yml*:

```
sylius.checkout.step.delivery.template: '@CoreBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/Checkout/Step/delivery.html.twig'
sylius.checkout_scenario.class: ZDG\CoreBundle\Checkout\CheckoutProcessScenario
```

and then there is checkoutStep, but those are only changed files.
I've looked into `state-machine.yml`, but it only defines states of order and payment, which i do not wish to modify.

Comment: Please add additional details, code samples of your implementation. The answers couldn't very specific, and will be mostly guesses.

Comment: as you are using `sylius_checkout_purchase` from core, PurchaseStep.php got some payment retrieval (checks) inside there. Try copying the logic of PurchaseStep.php and disable/dump the payment logic there. You'll have to either implement your own PurchaseSetp or programaticaly set DummyPayment as the payment method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution was les than expected: During pruchase step an event is triggered (sylius.checkout.purchase.complete), which has a listiner returning a response according to payment status. If status is not finished, it takes a parameter from container and redirects to provided url. This url is hardcoded in  `sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.xml:324`

Answer (score 0):

if you implemented custom class implementing `ProcessScenarioInterface`

There is also state machine configuration that could affect the redirection.
You will have to configure, what to do after each state change of the order.

Have a look in `Sylius\CoreBundle\Resources\config\state-machine.yml`

You can also check this for better understanding https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/wiki/Status